# Cannot resolve findViewById in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment, findviewbyid

i am trying to get id from fragment xml so here is the code
the error is
" Cannot resolve the method findViewById "

Is there anyway of which I can use `findViewById` in Fragment ?

```
public class Slide_Teacher_Add extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText teacher_id_number;
private EditText teacher_fullname;
private EditText teacher_lesson;
private EditText teacher_contact;

private Button btn_add_teacher;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_slide__teacher_add,container,false);
    return v;

    teacher_id_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teacher_id_number);
    teacher_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teacher_fullname);
    teacher_lesson = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teacher_lesson);
    teacher_contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teacher_contact);

    btn_add_teacher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_teacher);


    btn_add_teacher.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `onViewCreated` function without need to `Inflate` view. such as :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.findViewById(...);
    //....
}
```

Or You must call `findViewById` function from `v` object class (`View`). such as :

```
teacher_id_number = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_id_number);
```

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, you are calling `findViewById()` after the return statement so they wont be executed at all. Next, you need to call `findViewById()` on the context of a view as in `view.findViewById(int);` so rewrite the code as :

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_slide__teacher_add,container,false);
teacher_id_number = v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_id_number); //Note this line
//other tasks you need to do
return v;
```

making sure the `return` is the last statement of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Code after `return` can not be reached, that's first remark. Next  `findViewById()` is not defined into `Fragment` you have to exctract the view from it's parent, the inflated view. So your code should be like this:

```java
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_slide__teacher_add,container,false);


    teacher_id_number = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_id_number);
    teacher_fullname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_fullname);
    teacher_lesson = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_lesson);
    teacher_contact = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_contact);

    btn_add_teacher = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_teacher);


    btn_add_teacher.setOnClickListener(this);

   return v;
```

Answer (score 0):

add v before find.... like this:

```
teacher_id_number = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_id_number);
teacher_fullname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_fullname);
teacher_lesson = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_lesson);
teacher_contact = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_contact);

btn_add_teacher = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_teacher);

return v;
```

and you `return v;` inside there. need to move it to bottom as well.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to take View's reference from the inflated layout.

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_slide__teacher_add,container,false);
    teacher_id_number = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_id_number);
    teacher_fullname = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_fullname);
    teacher_lesson = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_lesson);
    teacher_contact = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_contact);
    btn_add_teacher = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_teacher);
    return v;
```

Comment: @m-andre-juliansyah do like this inside your onCreateView()